# Create summary value when using group_by and summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

I often want to show change given a baseline year. For example, how much has something changed since a given year as a percentage? The `gapminder` dataset provides an excellent example:

[image: change in population]

To start to get the answer, you would `group_by` year and continent, and `summarize` the sum the the population. But how do you get a summary value that is the population of 1952?

```
library(gapminder)
gapminder %>%
  group_by(year, continent) %>%
  summarize(tot_pop = sum(as.numeric(pop)),
            SUMMARY_VAL = POP_SUM_1952,
            CHG_SINCE_1952 = (tot_pop - SUMMARY_VAL ) / SUMMARY_VAL ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = CHG_SINCE_1952, color = continent)) +
  geom_line()
```

FYI, gapminder looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 1,704 x 6
   country     continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
   <fct>       <fct>     <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan Asia       1952    28.8  8425333      779.
 2 Afghanistan Asia       1957    30.3  9240934      821.
 3 Afghanistan Asia       1962    32.0 10267083      853.
 4 Afghanistan Asia       1967    34.0 11537966      836.
 5 Afghanistan Asia       1972    36.1 13079460      740.
 6 Afghanistan Asia       1977    38.4 14880372      786.
 7 Afghanistan Asia       1982    39.9 12881816      978.
 8 Afghanistan Asia       1987    40.8 13867957      852.
 9 Afghanistan Asia       1992    41.7 16317921      649.
10 Afghanistan Asia       1997    41.8 22227415      635.
# ... with 1,694 more rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to come up with a one step solution. In the meantime here's a simple two step solution -

```
pop_1952 <- filter(gapminder, year == 1952) %>%
  group_by(continent) %>%
  summarise(tot_pop_1952 = sum(pop, na.rm = T))

gapminder %>%
  group_by(year, continent) %>%
  summarize(tot_pop = sum(as.numeric(pop))) %>%
  left_join(pop_1952, by = "continent") %>%
  mutate(
    CHG_SINCE_1952 = (tot_pop - tot_pop_1952) / tot_pop_1952
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = CHG_SINCE_1952, color = continent)) +
  geom_line()
```

Here's a solution in a single chain if that helps (still technically two steps I guess) -

```
gapminder %>%
  mutate(
    tot_pop_1952 = ave(as.numeric(pop)*(year == 1952), continent, FUN = sum)
  ) %>%
  group_by(year, continent) %>%
  summarize(
    tot_pop = sum(as.numeric(pop)),
    tot_pop_1952 = mean(tot_pop_1952),
    CHG_SINCE_1952 = (tot_pop - tot_pop_1952) / tot_pop_1952
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = CHG_SINCE_1952, color = continent)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the `ave()` function is what I was looking for, but I didn't know it existed. Edit: It appears you have to group the function twice. I wonder if there is a more elegant solution. It's not clear why the second time to get the population in 1952 you use `mean()`.

Answer (score 0):

A one step solution with `dplyr`.

```
  gapminder %>%
    group_by(year, continent) %>%
    summarize(tot_pop = sum(as.numeric(pop))) %>%
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(CHG_POP = tot_pop - tot_pop[year == 1952]) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = year, y = tot_pop, color = continent)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Here is the code slightly modified to achieve what I needed.
```    gapminder %>%
      group_by(year, continent) %>%
      summarize(tot_pop = sum(as.numeric(pop))) %>%
      ungroup() %>% 
      mutate(CHG_POP = (tot_pop - tot_pop[year == 1952])/tot_pop[year == 1952]) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = year, y = CHG_POP, color = continent)) +
      geom_line()```